# Some mistakes regarding the /chrome, /google-chrome, and /chromium

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request, retagging

I was just wondering what's up with the tags [chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome), [google-chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), and [chromium](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chromium).

At the moment, [chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) is symlinked to [chromium](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chromium), and not [google-chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome). However, "chrome" is more likely to refer to Google's Chrome than Chromium. I was just wondering why this is. Is it an accident? Intentional? Something else? (I don't know what other possibilities there are, but you never know...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[google-chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) was just an oversight; I merged it into [chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) since [chrome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome) had considerably more instances, so now all three are grouped together. We normally only make synonyms if there's a history of people using both instances; [tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) and [tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) aren't synonyms because neither exists

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. Also, I meant the meta tag `tag`, not the normal tag (which, as you stated, diddn't exist.) Sorry for the ambiguity there.